# synchronize html-php comboBox with database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, combobox

I've some part of my php script :

```
<?
    $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
    $res=mysql_select_db("psi",$cn) or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
    $sql = "select names from list;";
    $res=mysql_query($sql) or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
?>
<select name="namez" size=1>
<?
    while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
     echo "<option value=" .$ri. "</option>";
    }
echo "</select> ";
?>
```

I want to make the comboBox has menu taken from "names" field through my database, but it still has no menu?

Comment: So what is it that stops you from doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
<select name="namez">
<?
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  {
     echo '<option value="'.$row['names'].'">'.$row['names'].'</option>';
  }
  echo "</select> ";
?>
```

Comment: ok thanks, it works with : echo "<option value=" .$ri['names'] . ">" . $ri['names'] . "</option>";

Comment: Good to hear! Another thing: I would recommend removing the trailing semicolon from your SQL query like `select names from list";` because semicolons in queries may cause problems depending on which database and driver you use. And you should wrap the option values in quotes as shown in my example, otherwise you may experience problems if values contain white-spaces. If my suggestion worked for you, would you mark it as answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$ri would be an array, so try

```
'<option value="' . $ri['dbColname'] . '">' . $ri['dbColname'] . "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

$ri is just an element of your result. First you need to fetch the name from it then display it. What are the field names in your table? So it would be something like

```
echo "<option value=" .$ri["id"].">".$ri["name"]. "</option>";
```